# Pick and place execution in Simulation_"Solution found but controller failed during execution"

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-control, ros-kinetic, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to execute pick and place task using jaco arm in simulation.I am able to successfully send Pickup goals to moveit pick action server.In the Rviz GUI i am able to see the pickup actions and while executing it on simulated robot, I am getting following error,once the arm has reached the approach position
`"Solution found but controller failed during execution"` in the terminal from which i executed the script.

`"Controller kate/jaco2_gripper_controller/follow_joint_trajectory failed with error code INVALID_GOAL"` in the moveit terminal.

`"Trajectory message contains waypoints that are not strictly increasing in time."` in simulation terminal.

Can someone help me out in this regard?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287516/pick-and-place-execution-in-simulation_%22solution-found-but-controller-failed-during-execution%22/) by [ARB](https://answers.ros.org/users/32980/arb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ARB](https://answers.ros.org/users/32980/arb/) on 2018-04-04**:
@gvdhoorn Can u have a look at it?Seems like problem with gripper controller!!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
Why are you pinging me exactly?

**Comment by [ARB](https://answers.ros.org/users/32980/arb/) on 2018-04-04**:
Have read similar kind of conversations from you in MoveIt users google groups?Thought you will be the right person to approach.Currently having no clue of what's going wrong.Sorry for the inconvenience.

**Comment by [ARB](https://answers.ros.org/users/32980/arb/) on 2018-04-06**:
After going through many rostopic echo steps,I have found that once the arm reaches pre-grasp pose.Move group is sending commands to gripper with only two points in joint trajectory msg having same time of start.
Gazebo side,gripper controller is followjointtrajectory type and not accepting points

**Comment by [ARB](https://answers.ros.org/users/32980/arb/) on 2018-04-06**:
with same time of start.
In the end question turns out to be Is any gripper controller available which takes only two points having same time of start and executes the trajectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When arm reaches pre-grasp position,MoveGroup sends Pre_grasp gripper pose to gripper with only two way points having same time_of_start value.Joint trajectory controller doesn't accept the points with same time_of_start value.

I overcame this problem by using katana_gazebo_plugin for gripper instead of normal Follow_joint_trajectory controller.I just have to edit the open and close angle values in the [source code of katana_gripper_grasp_controller.cpp](https://github.com/uos/katana_driver/tree/kinetic/katana_gazebo_plugins/src).

---

Originally posted by [ARB](https://answers.ros.org/users/32980/arb/) with karma: 51 on 2018-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0